# Dictionary with 3 dictionaries in it

Tags: python, dictionary

So i managed to convert 3 txt files into a list into a dictionary, but now i have to put those 3 dictionaries into a super dictionary with the following structure.

"123-45-6789":{"hw":[98,89,92,75], "quiz":[45,36,42,50,29,27,40,41], "exam":[175,157]}

i made a default dictionary with all the studentids that all have no values 
and i have three dictionaries called examList, hwList, and quizList that have the following structure (length of values vary)

{'709-40-8165': [168, 98], '560-33-3099': [176, 16]}

so the question is how can i iterate through the the default studentid dictionary to append the following dictionaries?

Here is some of the code

```
fullRoster= dict()
    idList= []
    quizList= []
    hwList= []
    examList= []
    studentids= open("studentids.txt", "r")
    idList= [line.rstrip()for line in studentids]
    studentids.close()
    idList= dict.fromkeys(idList)
    #hwFile converted into a list and then into a dictionary
    #the exam and homework files follow the same structure
    hwFile= open("hwscores.txt", "r")
    hwList= [line.rstrip().split() for line in hwFile]
    hwFile.close()
    #searches for similar ids then places quiz score into single list
    for i in range (15):
        for k in range ((len(hwList))):
            if hwList[i][0]== hwList[k][0] and i!=k:
                hwList[i].append((hwList[k][1]))
    hwList= hwList[:15]
    #adds zero if hw list is not 5
    for i in range (15):
        if len(hwList[i])!=5:
            while len(hwList[i])<5:
                hwList[i].append(0)
    #dictionary comprehension to create dictionary
    hwList= {l[0]: [int(x) for x in l[1:]] for l in hwList}
```

Comment: Your issue will be better illustrated if you can show some code and reference that code to explain what is happening with your issue. It will let the readers also have a faster/better understanding on how to help you.

Comment: @idjaw just edited

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like this:

```
# Example exam, hw, and quiz score dicts:
examList = {'709-40-8165': [168, 98], '560-33-3099': [176, 16]}
hwList =  {'709-40-8165': [15, 10], '602-33-3099': [17, 5]}
quizList  =  {'709-40-8165': [15, 10]}

# Add scores for that student ID
def add_scores(superList, scoreList, scoreType):
    for studentID,value in scoreList.items():
        if studentID not in superList.keys():
            superList[studentID] = {}
        superList[studentID][scoreType] = value

superList = {}
add_scores(superList, examList, 'exam')
add_scores(superList, quizList, 'quiz')
add_scores(superList, hwList, 'hw')

print(superList)
```

This gives:

```
{'602-33-3099': {'hw': [17, 5]}, '709-40-8165': {'exam': [168, 98], 'hw': [15, 10], 'quiz': [15, 10]}, '560-33-3099': {'exam': [176, 16]}}
```

It iterates over each `dict` and adds in the scores for that student ID.

Answer (score 0):

The following code elaborates on the answer from [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5626104/brian).

The function will copy the student records, so it always returns a copy of the records passed into it, if any, otherwise it returns a new dictionary.

```
import copy

def add_scores(scores, description, records=None):
    """Add scores to student records.

    Use this function to add scores for multiple different
    kinds of graded exercises in the following way:

    >>> exam_scores = {'709-40-8165': [168, 98], '560-33-3099': [176, 16]}
    >>> hw_scores =  {'709-40-8165': [15, 10], '602-33-3099': [17, 5]}
    >>> quiz_scores  =  {'709-40-8165': [15, 10]}
    >>> records = add_scores(exam_scores, 'exam')
    >>> records = add_scores(quiz_scores, 'quiz', records)
    >>> records = add_scores(hw_scores, 'hw', records)
    >>> records == {'560-33-3099': {'exam': [176, 16]}, \
                    '602-33-3099': {'hw': [17, 5]}, \
                    '709-40-8165': {'exam': [168, 98], \
                                    'hw': [15, 10], \
                                    'quiz': [15, 10]}}
    True

    Parameters
    ----------
    scores : dict
        each key is a student id
        each value is a list of scores
    description : str
        describes the type of score being added
    records : dict
        each key is a student id
        each value is a dictionary of
        {description: scores}

    Returns
    -------
    records : dict
        student records in the format described above
    """
    records = copy.deepcopy(records) if records else {}
    for student_id, student_scores in scores.items():
        record = records.setdefault(student_id, {})
        record[description] = \
                record.get(description, []) + student_scores
    return records
```